# How do I find the correct plugin?

Tags: 8, plugins

As an Drupal 7 developer I'm currently trying to get into Drupal 8.
I got a problem finding the right plugin.

For example, I simple want to change the text of a node link "**read more**" into "**read more >**".

Leaving the templates out, I would google for Drupal 7 something like "drupal hook -what I want- alter" and found the correct hook. How can I find the correct plugin?

Especially for this case, there `hook_node_links_alter()`. Should I use this, or is it just for legacy and I should prefer a other way?

Comment: One thing that helps transition from Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 is the list of [Change Records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal).

Comment: Not everything in Drupal is a plugin. Generally speaking, there isn't a way to find a plugin, if you don't know at least which class is used to annotate it.

Comment: _Should I use this, or is it just for legacy_ The docs are usually very good with deprecation notices. If you don't see a deprecation notice for a function, there's a good chance it hasn't been deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific example you make, there aren't plugins involved. The hook in invoked from [NodeViewBuilder::renderLinks()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeViewBuilder.php/function/NodeViewBuilder%3A%3ArenderLinks/8.2.x), which executes the following code.

```
  $links = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__node',
    '#pre_render' => array('drupal_pre_render_links'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
  );

  if (!$is_in_preview) {
    $entity = Node::load($node_entity_id)->getTranslation($langcode);
    $links['node'] = static::buildLinks($entity, $view_mode);

    // Allow other modules to alter the node links.
    $hook_context = array(
      'view_mode' => $view_mode,
      'langcode' => $langcode,
    );
    \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('node_links', $links, $entity, $hook_context);
  }
  return $links;
```

To know if a plugin is involved, you need to read the documentation. [Plugin API in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/plugins) give the general documentation, but then you need to read more specific documentation pages, for example [Block API in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/block_api).
A plugin could be annotated, so in some cases you can find any plugin implemented by Drupal core by looking at the classes annotated with a specific class, which is what happens with form input elements, which are classes annotated with [`\Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\FormElement`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Annotation%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.2.x). The documentation page gives a list of the classes annotated with that `Annotation` class, so you can find any plugins of that type.

Then, as [@CLive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200289/how-do-i-find-the-correct-plugin#comment242153_200289) said, if you are simply wondering if you should use a hook, just look at the documentation page for that hook: If it has been deprecated, the documentation reports that, and tells you exactly what you should use: a different hook, a plugin, a specific class.
Also, as said from [@mradcliffe](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200289/how-do-i-find-the-correct-plugin#comment242140_200289), [change records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal) reports the changes done in Drupal, and for which version. They are helpful if you want to look at the changes that could interest the code you are writing.